# Open documents with GDocs on browser

Tags: google

I've just installed Ubuntu 22.04 and connected my Google Drive.
On the file explorer, if I click on a GDocs document from my GDrive folder, it opens it properly on GDocs app in the browser (Chrome).
Is it possible to set the same configuration for all the documents (.docx, .doc, .xls,...)?

Comment: More info and examples of what it is you are trying to do is needed.

Comment: Sorry but I don't understand what I forgot to specify. I indicated the operating system and indicated that I would like to open files (specifying extensions) with the application within the browser (I specified which) as happens with other files (specified)

Comment: You are trying to open a .doc file with a browser?

Comment: with Google Documents. On Nautilus if I double-click on a GDoc file, the related Google Application opens on Chrome. Is it possible to have the same behavior with a .doc or .xls?

Comment: I do not think so.